# How can I make a script to change the text color in google docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I don't have an example to give because I couldn't find one. But I tried using Google Apps Scripts to make a script to change the text color of a highlighted text. It ended up selecting the whole document when I tried it. And no, I can't give an example because I got mad that it didn't work after 3 hours of trying.

Comment: Please don't start a new duplicate question but edit or improve the existing one.  Web Applications SE is a bit different than a discussion forum. Please take the [Tour] and review [ask]. We want to help you so just be patient as you learn the ropes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a response to another question and that question should be edited.